# Can an app running inside a Docker container write to its container's filesystem?

Tags: docker, logging

I have a Python Tornado server that I've been trying to Dockerize lately. The only issue I couldn't solve is logging. Previously the server wrote logs to files within its directory, using the `logging` module. When run as a container though, no more logs are written at all, even inside the container's file system. I tried creating new files, and that doesn't work either. The conclusion seems to be that the app cannot modify its container's file system, but that makes no sense to me.

I also read about volumes and binding container directories to host directories. I tried that too, and still no files were created or written to.

I know that I probably could solve the logging problem by redirecting the server's logs to `stdout` & `stderr` and using docker logging, but I want to understand why the container's file system seems immutable.

Answer (score 1):

The container's filesystem is not immutable, but the log files aren't being written there. They shouldn't be; if they were, you'd lose the logs when the container stopped.

You are already using docker logging: "By default, Docker captures the standard output (and standard error) of all your containers, and writes them in files using the JSON format" with the default [`json-file` logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/).

See the Docker docs on configuring logging: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

The log files are created on the host:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container_id>/<container_id>-json.log
```

You tail the logs from the host via

```
docker logs -f <container_id>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As visible in the question, I already knew that Docker captured the stdout & stderr in logs on the host, I just wanted to know why I couldn't write to files in the container. I haven't used Docker before and I couldn't find info on this subject.